# process.env undefined in Node app

Tags: process, node.js, duostack

When running my Node app with `node server.js`, `process.env` returns `undefined`, so I'm unable to access any environment variables. This also seems to occur when I attempt to deploy my app to [Duostack](http://www.duostack.com).

Calling `process.env` from the command line seems to work, though:

```
$ node
> process.env
{ MANPATH: '/opt/local/share/man:',
  TERM_PROGRAM: 'Apple_Terminal',
...
```

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I figured it out. `process` is an object (https://nodejs.org/api/process.html), but I'd defined my own function (also called `process`) that overwrote it. Changing the name of my function fixed the problem.

Comment: I had this problem too, don't create a method name `process`

Comment: I can't believe I copy-pasta'd a process() function for testing only to find out it's a reserved object. So much for dangerous tutorials.

Comment: Funny how many people did that silly same mistake !