# Node/React: os.platform() returns 'browser' instead of actual OS

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a React app created using 'create-react-app', containing the following code:

```
const os = require("os");

const testFunc = () => {
  console.log(os.platform());
}
```

This results in the value 'browser' rather than my OS (Windows). What's happening here and how do I get the correct value?

Additional Info:

- This code is in a JS file (not TS)
- `process.platform` returns 'undefined' in Chrome Dev Tools console but 'win32' when running Node via CLI

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Platform issue in require('os')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49651592/platform-issue-in-requireos)

Comment: according the document(https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_platform) Your code has no problem. Please check your process.platform or use a npm library.

Comment: @vuluu `process.platform` returns undefined.

Comment: that's a problem. Lets take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457397/process-env-undefined-in-node-app

Comment: When I run Node via CLI and type 'process.platform', I get 'win32' as expected. Could the issue be due to something that React does? I use 'npm start' to launch the app in browser